# How do I model this shape of a lipstick?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I've made lipsticks before but not from this angle. I've looked at some tutorials on youtube but none seem to have this shape.

Comment: do you have the side view?

Comment: @moonboots not for the same lipstick. I've made the side angle before but they dont look this angular when I rotate it. I like the dramatic shape on this.

Comment: @moonboots [Sideview I guess ...](https://cdn.cultbeauty.com/slots-img/koskos003_kosas_weightlesslipstick_rosewater_1560x1960-vuok1jpg) They all looks the same.

Comment: @vklidu, the one you show is round on its peak, which is not the case here

Comment: @moonboots I think OP example is just a more spiky, but general shape and "cut" is the same ... but I can be a wrong for sure :)

Answer (score 10):

Start from *Sphere* and Delete <kbd>X</kbd> lower part, Extrude <kbd>E</kbd> bottom loop

[image]

Select tip vertex and enable *Proportional Editing* <kbd>O</kbd> with **Root** type selected

[image]

Use *Boolean modifier >* **Exact** to cut desired part under angle by Plane
(possible with version 2.92)

[image]

A bit of adjustment ...

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea about the boolean modifier till now but it seems very useful!

Answer (score 8):

You can start with an *UV Sphere*, stretch it:

[image]

[image]

Cut if off with a *Boolean* modifier:

[image]

Begin to correct the topology, use the knife tool, <kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>Z</kbd> to cut through:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Pull up the peak:

[image]

Make sure that the surface stays flat:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any tips on how to correct the topology?

Comment: use the knife tool (very useful), the Proportional Editing option, slide the edge loops with GG, etc...

Comment: Thank you again for the help! I've been able to begin the process though I feel like I'll make this into another question - I feel like I made a mess with the knife tool since I dont know what is "good" topology. I'm going to do some self studying and may post about this again soon.

Comment: good topology would be a topology that follows the shape and avoid tris and ngons, even though some tris and ngons are sometimes ok. So for example, from picture 4 to 5 I used the knife to simply cut the new edges, then dissolve the old ones and end up with quads only, but the topology of picture 4 would have worked as well, I just tried to make things look good   ;)

Answer (score 7):

Starting with an octogon, you can model the bottom and top shapes:

[image]

Join them (bridge edge loops) and shear the top part:

[image]

Fill the top part extrude and scale down <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> then do it again to the center (scale 0, and remove doubles):

[image]

Add a loop cut and scale a bit this loop and the bottom:

[image]

Bevel this part (and add subdivision and shader...):

[image]

Blend file with steps included:

[image]

Comment: Ah, thank you!!

Comment: I like the non-boolean solution with precise control on the topology.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the same steps as described from lemon, but instead of adding loops to sharpen the edge you can use EDGE CREASE (Shift + E) to a single edge. This way you can avoid unnecessary geometry.

[image]

[image]